# Receiving TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - why?

Tags: javascript, string, string-length

I'm trying to return a simple greeting message which takes an inputted name, whereas if the string is empty will return a generic 'Hello, World!' message. It also looks out for capitalisation errors and will edit the name input to ensure it is properly capitalised. This is what I've got so far.

```
   function hello(name) {
  if (name.length > 0 && typeof name == 'string') {
    let fixed = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    return "Hello, " + fixed + "!";
  }
  else {
    return "Hello, World!";
  }
}
```

It doesn't appear to take the length of the name argument and is the only test it fails on!

Comment: Please share how you call this method to clarify your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check if is a string

```js
function hello(name) {
  if (typeof name == 'string' && name.length > 0) { // Changed
    let fixed = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    return "Hello, " + fixed + "!";
  }
  else {
    return "Hello, World!";
  }
}
```

Comment: That was the perfect answer, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your `undefined | null` case is failing.
This we can handle by adding a default value.

```js
function hello(name = '') { //changed
  if (typeof name == 'string' && name.length > 0) { //changed
    let fixed = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    return "Hello, " + fixed + "!";
  }
  else {
    return "Hello, World!";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 3rd party lib like `lodash` to make it easier

```
const { capitalize } = require('lodash');
`Hello ${capitalize('YOU')}`;
```